# Multiple Subdomains, Common Route Pattern

Tags: python, design-patterns, subdomain, pyramid, routes

So what I want is to have one pyramid app with the following:

- If a user goes to `control.blah.com/` I want them to get page A
- If a user goes to `www.blah.com/` I want them to get page B

What I tried:

```py
# Pregen for "Control" Subdomain
def pregen(request, elements, kw):
    kw['_app_url'] = 'http://control.blah.com'
    return elements, kw

# Custom predicate for "Control" Subdomain
def req_sub(info, request):
    return request.host.startswith('control')

def main(global_config, **settings):
    """
    This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
    """

    engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
    Session.configure(bind=engine)

    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.include('pyramid_jinja2')
    config.add_jinja2_extension('jinja2.ext.do')
    config.include('pyramid_tm')
    config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)

    # Control Subdomain
    config.add_route('control_index', '/', custom_predicates=(req_sub, ),
            pregenerator=pregen)

    # Main Subdomain
    config.add_route('index', '/')

    config.scan()

    app = config.make_wsgi_app()

    return app
```

So now, going to `control.blah.com/` results in the `control_index` view being called, but when I go to `www.blah.com/` I get a 404 Not Found.

Similarly, if I move the `config.add_route('index', '/')` before the subdomain line, then I get the opposite problem.

Is it possible to get what I want, or do the routes need to have different patterns (AKA. Can't have 2 routes with the `/` pattern)

Comment: Have you looked at the host header on the requests when they come in?

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the custom predicates looks correct, but you may be right about the routes colliding with the same pattern. This is what I would try:

```
class DomainOverrideMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.application = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        if "HTTP_HOST" in environ and "control.blah.com" in environ['HTTP_HOST']:
            environ['PATH_INFO'] = "/control" + environ['PATH_INFO']
        return self.application(environ, start_response)



def main(global_config, **settings):
    """
    This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
    """

    engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
    Session.configure(bind=engine)

    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.include('pyramid_jinja2')
    config.add_jinja2_extension('jinja2.ext.do')
    config.include('pyramid_tm')
    config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)

    # Control Subdomain
    #Change this subdomain to handle the modified path
    config.add_route('control_index', '/control/', custom_predicates=(req_sub, ),
            pregenerator=pregen)

    # Main Subdomain
    config.add_route('index', '/')

    config.scan()

    #Change this to call the override
    app = DomainOverrideMiddleware(config.make_wsgi_app())
```

So this modifies the path internally within the app with a '/control' prefix to handle different routing (avoiding conflicts), but the path to the user should appear unchanged.
Untested, but works in theory.